# Undo apt-get remove --purge

Tags: apt, bash, python, regex, purge

I wanted a fresh install of Python and ran `sudo apt-get remove --purge python`. Apparently it has killed almost everything I had installed in my system.

Looking at the `history.log` I guess I could manually install the packages again, but there are hundreds of them, I can't just copy paste.

Ironically, python is still installed. Could I perform some replace regex with it so I can fix this mess? Or with bash.

Comment: If `apt` is still working: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: @muru thanks, now 140 MB are being installed. However the purge removed around 350.

Comment: @muru well now I am not sure, if downloaded or installed. But I still have some packages missing, `ubuntu-desktop` just helped me get back some of it (which is a lot, thanks).

Comment: @muru nvm, I managed to make my own python script and it's already installing the missing packages. Installign `ubuntu-desktop` package helped a lot though, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

First I ran `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` as I was told in the comments, then I copied the part of `/var/log/apt/history.log` concerning the purge action, and ran on it the following python script I made. Probably someone more skilled in regex would cry when seeing how I did it, but it worked for me:

```
import re

f = open('remove.log', 'r')
s = ""
for i in f:
    s += i + '\n'

s = re.sub(':.*?', '', s)
s = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', s)
s = re.sub(',', '', s)
s = re.sub('amd64', '', s)

f = open('replaced.txt', 'w')
f.write(s)
```

Then I could see a `Install` block and `Purge` block in `replaced.txt`, so I would just `sudo apt-get install` all the packages in the first block, and then in the second.

And voilà, apparently.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. @dabadaba's script worked great, but I found manually installing each package to be a little tedious.

Here is a python script I wrote to automate installing the packages listed in the `replaced.txt` file created in @dabadaba's answer

```
import subprocess

f = open('replaced.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
    if line.startswith('Install') or line.startswith('Purge'):
        packages = line.split()
        for i in range(1, len(packages)):
            print 'Do you want to install ' + packages[i] + '? [y/n]'
            input = raw_input()
            if input == 'y':
                print 'beginning install'
                p = subprocess.Popen('apt-get install ' + packages[i], shell=True)
                p.wait()
            else:
                print 'not installing'
```

Comment: This does not install the version package was before the purge